# How to deploy/replicate/copy a SQL Server 2005 database including CLR objects to multiple servers

Tags: sql-server, deployment, clr

We maintain a generic tools database at work that contains useful stored procedures, functions, and the odd lookup table.  It also contains some CLR objects which need to be included.

We have around 10 servers and want to have a copy of this database available on each instance inclusding CLR functions..

I plan to nominate one DB as the master and then replicate/logship the db to other instances on a nightly basis.  I would also like to be able to kick off the replication by hand if necessary.

Any advice on how this can be achieved?

Thanks : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept this thread open in hopes that someone would come up with something clever.  Here's what I came up with:

1) You could implement the log shipping you're talking about and create a read-only snapshot of the log shipping target database on the non-master servers.  You'd drop and re-create the snapshot every day.

2) Back up to a location that's available to all the servers and just do a straight restore every day.

Comment: It should; log shipping provides a facsimile of your database, objects included.  However, I invite healthy skepticism.  Give it a go and see how it works for you!

Comment: Forgot to say this did work and is now in daily use. All the objects are copying, including CLR, and working perfectly.  Thanks for your help : )

Comment: Out of curiosity, which method did you use?

Comment: The first one, a master database then just log-shipped to the non-masters when necessary : )